# How to get the recent baselines of a project in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

Can we get the list of baselines of a project in clearcase within in a certain time period, say, last 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

The [cleartool lsbl](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsbl.htm) command usually lists baselines:

- per streams
- from the oldest to the most recent

If you can restrict your search to one stream (`ct lsbl -stream ...`), you need to list everything and then filter the result.
You can use the [fmt option](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) to display only the name of the baseline and its date.

```
 cleartool lsbl -fmt "%d %n\" -stream...
```

You would get results like:

```
2007-01-10T12:41:45+01:00 MYBL_20070110.1263
2007-01-25T16:33:13+01:00 MYBL_20070125.3901
2007-01-26T12:25:23+01:00 MYBL_20070126.7020
2007-01-31T12:21:44+01:00 MYBL_20070131.7277
2007-02-01T16:54:21+01:00 MYBL_20070201.7671
```

From there, you can filter and/or sort the results.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. I tried that ,but for me it displayed all the baselines in the alphabetical order. could you please also provide more details on filtering the result. If you meant filtering the result by creating a unix script. could you please provide more details on that , as I havent written any scripts so far.

Comment: @aquero: I have added in the answer the options to only display what you can use for filtering/ordering.